# vertx HTTPS (SSL/TLS) server does not work. I cannot access https://localhost

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2, vert.x

I have created HTTPS server in `vert.x`.

```java
vertx.createHttpServer(
    new HttpServerOptions()
        .setSsl(true)
        .setKeyStoreOptions(new JksOptions()
            .setPath("path/to/keystore")
            .setPassword("password")
        )
).requestHandler( (HttpServerRequest req) -> {
    System.out.println("Access.");
    req.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    req.response().end("Hello world!");
    // ...
}).listen(80, "localhost");
```

I have created keystore with `keytool`.

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore -storetype jks
```

I have succeeded in deploying verticle. But the server does not response.

Access to https://localhost gives nothing. Even the log is not printed.

What is wrong?

I have tried some options like below.

```java
vertx.createHttpServer(
    new HttpServerOptions()
        .setSsl(true)
        .setKeyStoreOptions(new JksOptions()
            .setPath("path/to/keystore")
            .setPassword("password")
        )
        // .setUseAlpn(true)
        // .setTrustOptions(new JksOptions()
        //  .setPath("C:/Recoeve/keystore")
        //  .setPassword("Xs41Kipid$ps15")
        // )
        // .setClientAuthRequired(false)
        // .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.NONE)
        // .addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol(TCPSSLOptions.DEFAULT_ENABLED_SECURE_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOLS.get(1))
        // .addEnabledSecureTransportProtocol("TLSv1.3")
        // .setEnabledSecureTransportProtocols(TCPSSLOptions.DEFAULT_ENABLED_SECURE_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOLS)
).requestHandler( (HttpServerRequest req) -> {
    // ...
}).listen(80, "localhost");
```

But the code gives runtime exception.

================================================================

Recently editted:

That was a default port problem. I though that default port of HTTPS is also 80.

Take a look at [kipid's blog :: Vert.x https (SSL/TLS) server](https://kipid.tistory.com/entry/Vertx-%EB%A1%9C-https-SSLTLS-server-%EB%A7%8C%EB%93%A4%EA%B8%B0).

And for complete HTTPS server, I think I need to buy RSA keys. Keys from java command (keytool) give warning to clients on access of my server through internet browser.

Comment: Try with `setLogActivity(true)` and using a logging library to see debug logs.

Comment: Where are you expecting that log to be printed out?
What do you mean exactly by "gives nothing"? The provided source code should given nothing as response to the SSL/TLS request.

Comment: @metaphori setLogActivity(true) gives this error. null: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'concrete()' in type 'io.vertx.codegen.annotations.VertxGen': class file for io.vertx.codegen.annotations.VertxGen not found
C:\Recoeve\Recoeve.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                        .setLogActivity(true)
                        ^
  symbol:   method setLogActivity(boolean)
  location: class io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions

Comment: @tmarwen Without SSL/TLS settings, this code gives responses well to the browser's localhost access. But with SSL/TLS settings, it gives nothing. Even `System.out.println("Access.")` is not printed.

Comment: If a server offers https/ssl it should listen on port 443 also. Web browsers access the server port 443, when using an https address. Or have you tried to access `https://localhost:80` ?

Comment: I had an issue where `io.vertx.core.void deployVerticle(Verticle verticle, Handler<AsyncResult<String>> completionHandler)` was being used and the handler was silently ignoring `AsyncResult.cause()`, you might have a similar issue here

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the JKS certificate using the below command

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias aliasName -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystoreName.jks -validity 3650
```

You can use the default port of HTTPS ie 443

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me:

```
    JksOptions keyOptions = new JksOptions();
    keyOptions.setPath("path-to-your/keystore.jks");
    keyOptions.setPassword("changeit");

    vertx.createHttpServer(
      new HttpServerOptions()
        .setSsl(true)
        .setKeyStoreOptions(keyOptions)
    ).requestHandler( (HttpServerRequest req) -> {
      System.out.println("Access.");
      req.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
      req.response().end("Hello SSL world!");
    }).listen(8443, "localhost");
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me as you posted but with the following key store generation:

`keytool -genkey -alias server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks -validity 3650`